# What is the correct Doctype For HTML5?

Tags: html, doctype

I'm wondering what is the correct doctype for html5? I feel that it is something simple but its not working as I think it should.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML5></!DOCTYPE>
```

or is it something like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML5></HTML5>
```

Much appreciated for the help!

Comment: This is such a trivial question that could have been answered with Google.

Answer (score 1):

You really could have googled this, but i feel that your over thinking it.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

just have that at the top of the page, no need to close it...

Answer (score 1):

this should do...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
   ....
```

Comment: what does the lang="en" do?

Comment: @user3462195 it specifies the language of the page's content